# Persistence options for .NETCF

Tags: persistence, compact-framework

What are some options for persisting data on .NET compact framework 3.5? 
So far I know about the following:

DB options:

- sqlce
- sqlite

Serialization/deserialization options

- protobuf.net
- json.net

Are there any more you could suggest (even good comercial products)? Which would you suggest and why (pros/cons)? Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on your needs. If you are just storing a few user settings go with XML/binary serialization. If you have complex data go with a database like sqlite. CTacke has a good cross platform ORM that works well with SQLite. I typically don't serialize data that requires me to nest objects more than one deep. If I have to I implement the Memento pattern.

Comment: Tnx for the tip, did not know about OpenNetCF ORM. In my case, it's a bit more data, 1-2MB (it's not user settings), but I don't mind loading it all in memory when starting the application. I can query it in memory, and that's fine. Serialization seems a bit simpler but it doesn't let me save smaller pieces of data (it's either the entire object graph or nothing) so I think I'll go with the SQL+ORM route.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/), they have an open source version to try, and it [supports](http://www.db4o.com/s/compactframeworkdb.aspx) Compact Framework as well as full framework.

They've actually did a great work porting Mono.Cecil and System.Linq.Expressions to .NETCF for their product to work, so you get those as a bonus.